# How to retain image quality when scaling down in html/css

Tags: html, css

I am very new to html/css. For a project I am working on, I'm trying to scale down an image, however, when I do so, the image becomes very blurry. I've tried resizing the png itself, and it looks slightly better, but is still blurry. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<img style="display:block;float: left;
padding-right: 5px" width=140px height=150px
src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOAUA.png">

<img style="display:block;float: left;
padding-right: 5px" width=140px height=150px
src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTr2w.png">
```

Here the left image is original and the right image is resized.

Comment: Please add your code. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Can you share your html and your image?

Comment: @MaikLowrey I added the code

Comment: @Yong I added the code

Answer (score 2):

you can use the css scale transformation that allow you to scale down a image without loosing quality

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale()

```css
.scale {
  transform: scale(0.7); 
}
```

```html
<img style="display:block;float: left;
padding-right: 5px" 
src="https://i.ibb.co/HHqgNZ7/Portland-Timbers-logo-svg.png">

<img class="scale" style="display:block;float: left;
padding-right: 5px" 
src="https://i.ibb.co/HHqgNZ7/Portland-Timbers-logo-svg.png">
```

Comment: The image remained blurry when I scaled it as small as I needed it.

Comment: That is not the right answer of the problem! The Question Owner have two different Images and if he would to resize the thumbnail with css transform property it would also blurry.

Answer (score 1):

place a class on the image and then all you have to do is use
***object-fit: cover;***
***display: block;***

this will make it retain sharpness and lose all blur.

Answer (score 0):

### You can use `css` instead of any other converters in online

- if you want to scale down based on height or width and be proportional,
- then set *either* `height` *or* `width` to the value,
- and the other property to `auto`

Note: **Setting the other property to `auto` is not needed for this case**, it's only said for understanding easily

```css
.resizedI{
height:100px;
width:auto;
}
```

```html
<img style="display:block;float: left;
padding-right: 5px"
src="https://i.ibb.co/HHqgNZ7/Portland-Timbers-logo-svg.png">
<img style="display:block;float: left;
padding-right: 5px" class="resizedI"
src="https://i.ibb.co/HHqgNZ7/Portland-Timbers-logo-svg.png">
```

Comment: It's good quality when I zoom in, but remains blurry when the window is at 100%.

Comment: @EliMTZ can you send visual evidence for comparison,it looks fine for me

Comment: I'm not sure how, where should I send or upload?

Comment: It is also blurry when I zoom in, but that's just how zooming in works. You can't fix this, because it's how images work.

Comment: @ethry it's actually the opposite, it gets clearer when I zoom in for me

Comment: @EliMTZ upload in imagebb and send link in comments

Comment: i even support @ethry thats how it works for me on edge browser

Comment: @EliMTZ sorry, I don't understand the problem you're having?

Comment: @Neptotech-vishnu yeah, its how chromium-based browsers work I'm pretty sure

Comment: @Neptotech -vishnu first image at 100%: https://ibb.co/gTTSghJ second image when zoomed: https://ibb.co/qCLM23R

Comment: @EliMTZ sorry,it works for when the height is 100px,but when it is 20px i get same behaviour as you,if I find solution I will update it

Comment: @Neptotech -vishnu thank you for trying and let me know if you find a way!

Answer (score 0):

## This answer explains logic and not a `solution`

##### Things to consider

- In browser, or real world, when a image is to be reduced in size(scale down),some pixels are sure to be get lost
- No matter how the image renders, some pixels are to be get lost
- The way the image renders is only defining which pixel the image need to get lost,and what color...,anyway the pixel get lost
- This will not be so for 12k or HD like televisions or monitors, because there(in tv) in just a 1cm it has lots of pixels that can decide the clarity.
- So finally pixel will be lost according to the monitor's/device capacity, if the monitor is a good ones, the pixel wont be lost(may be lost but very less).

Answer (score 0):

Thumbnail original size:
[image]

The blur effect comes because you try a thumbnail to resize. You can do it with vector images like SVG but not with png, jpg etc.